# httpd.conf does not have default MPM entries in RHEL 7. What values should I put to limit the server to 2500 concurrent connections?

Tags: apache, rhel7

In the httpd.conf configuration file of apache 2.4.6. The default entries for serverlimit and maxclient etc are not given while in my RHEL6 box these values are provided. I need to limit my RHEL 7 server to a maximum of 2500 connections. Pls help.